# Merge tags 'nomenclature' and 'terminology'

Tags: discussion, retag-request

Answers to [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20234/difference-between-terminology-and-nomenclature) question assert that there is no difference in meaning between these two words.  So they should be merged?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Collins Cobuild English Dictionary:

> **Nomenclature**: The nomenclature of a
>   particular set of things is the system
>   of naming those things [formal]
>
> **Terminology**: The terminology of a
>   subject is the set of special words
>   and expressions used in connection
>   with it

My opinion is that we do not need both of these tags. I would say to keep "terminology" as it is more widely known/used than "nomenclature".

Comment: I think there's considerable overlap with *single-word-requests*, *word-choice*, *vocabulary*, *words*, *nomenclature*, *terminology*, and possibly several others. But where will it all end? We can't just tag everything as *language*.

Comment: I support merging these two tags, and will set up the synonyms myself if no one objects in the next day or two.

Comment: @JSBձոգչ Did you change your mind? See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

This has not been done, nor do I see any votes that it be done.

The [nomenclature](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nomenclature) has 83 questions and a tag wiki, while [terminology](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology) is considerably larger with over a 1,000 questions and two existing synonyms.